# How can I display all the characters after 20 characters in a string using PHP?

Tags: php, string, substring

For example, in the string given below:

```
$string = "adadadadadadadadaadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadaddadadadadaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaafewgewrehrejrejreerj";
```

I would like the output to consist of all the characters except the first 20.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: single character or all after 20 ?

Comment: Did you do any research at all? We are not here to do your homework. You are expected to do an effort yourself before you ask. Write in the question what you expect, what you have tried, and what results you actually get

Comment: Yes I want to display all after 20 but here the string is for the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
$string = "adadadadadadadadaadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadaddadadadadaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaafewgewrehrejrejreerj";

echo substr($string, 20)
```

And check output.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code,

```
echo substr($string, 20);
```

Documentation link of [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) which states Return part of a string depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you need  the right part of the string after the 20th character  you could use substr

```
$string = "adadadadadadadadaadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadaddadadadadaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaafewgewrehrejrejreerj";
$rest = substr($string, 20, -1);
```

see this for ref  http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `substr($string, $start)`

You can see the manual here http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

if you have to only print string then you can direct echo / print .
echo "your string";

Answer (score -1):

$twentieth_char = substr($string, 19, 1);